# How to connect UITableViewCell to UITableView from the same XIB?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I have XIB with `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`.

How should I connect this cell to tableView in my **cellForRowAtIndexPath**?

**EDITED**

[image]

**EDITED**

I simply want to use the cell from screen in tableView above this cell. I don't want to create class because i need only one label displayed

Thanks to everybody

Comment: you mean you wanna add custom cell ?

Comment: this cell should display only one text label, so I don't want to create new class... enough to use basic cell...

Comment: please show your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I think you did mistake.

Comment: You show different xib file , but you want to wire up to one files owner? Is it possible?

Comment: @Romowski Dear there is no need of custom cell if you wanna only title in that case you can use my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use this one if you wanna show only one label in table view. And there is no need of customcell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   UILabel *titleLbl;

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


        // -------------------- Label for Title Name ----------------------
        titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 7, 200, 13)];
        [titleLbl setTag:1];
        [cell addSubview:titleLbl];
    }
    else
    {
        titleLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
     }

     [titleLbl setText:@"Title"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your customcell.xib you need to do this

[image]

In your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ViewCustomCell";
        ViewCustomCell *objAlertCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (objAlertCustomCell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
            for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ViewCustomCell class]])
                {
                    objAlertCustomCell = (ViewCustomCell *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        objAlertCustomCell.lblAlertName.text = [[self.aryAlerts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"vAlertName"];
        objAlertCustomCell.lblDate.text = [[self.aryAlerts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"vDate"];
        objAlertCustomCell.lblDescription.text = [[self.aryAlerts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"vDescription"];
        return objAlertCustomCell;
```

Comment: @monahar. How can I connect my xib to segue?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new class by inheriting UITableViewCell (say TableCell) and in cellForRowAtIndexPath use the following code snippet

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
TableCell *cell = (TableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: this cell should display only one text label, so I don't want to create new class... enough to use basic cell... thanks

Comment: @Romowski Then How do you use customTableViewCell nib which you show.?

Answer (score 0):

CellForRowAtIndexpath and others are delegate methods.They not need to be "connected"

Include

```
@interface YOURTableViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

and connect the table to the datasource and delegates to files owner

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"TableCellXibName" owner:self options:nil];
```

Comment: cell & tableView are in the one XIB

Comment: why you do it? you take new view and and add in UITableViewCell,it takes just one minute solution..

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"currencyCellIdentifier";

    // Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
    CurrencyTableCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    // If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // Use the default cell style.
        cell = [[CurrencyTableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CurrencyTableCell"
                                                     owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set delegate and datasource to your tableviewView.

It can be made in two ways.

1) If your view controller is UITableViewController, just find TableViewDatasource and delegate in xib, and trag it to your files owner.

2) Otherwise If you use UIViewController..

In Your .h file

```
@interface YourViewController<UITableviewDelegate,UITableviewDatasource>
```

In viewDidload.

```
self.tableView1.delegate = self;
self.tableView1.datasource = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this source :
http://zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/